# How do i remove login button from a specific page in magento?

Tags: php, magento

How do i remove login button from a specific page in magento? I cant disable entire block but need to remove login button only from a specific page.

Comment: Define "login" button and specify which page please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this question assuming you mean the link inside the "account.links" area.

Let's save you want to remove it from the catalog product view.  The following should do it:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="account.links>
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: I was about to remove login button from a page named my stores. I removed it using remove tag in stores.xml page. Anyway your information is valueable... Thanks for the response. I m a little bit new to magento...